# Loading videoclips in background layer with Actionscript 2

Tags: background, actionscript, loading, actionscript-2

I am trying to load videoclips (or images) into the  background layer, based on the frame number, using the Actionscript 2  below, on Macromedia Flash 8 pro.

There are two layers; background and text layer.  The script loads clips alright  but it puts them in front of the text layer. The script is placed on frame 1 of background layer:-

What am I doing wrong here, please?

I am a newbie and got the script from some forums. I'd appreciate any help.. Thanks!

```
            mclListener.onLoadInit = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {};

            this.createEmptyMovieClip("image_mc",1);

            var mclListener:Object = new Object();

            mclListener.onLoadInit = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {};

            var image_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();

            image_mcl.addListener(mclListener);


            // the first clip on frame 1
            image_mcl.loadClip("movie1.swf", image_mc);

            onEnterFrame = function () {
             if (this._currentframe == 100) {
              image_mcl.loadClip("movie2.swf", image_mc);
             }
             if (this._currentframe == 200) {
              image_mcl.loadClip("movie3.swf", image_mc);
             }
            };
```

Comment: any chance of an answer .. or a hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have I sent this to the wrong section?  Could someone please advise?

Comment: Thank you very much, greg-449.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to this.  In the second line in the script:-

```
            this.createEmptyMovieClip("image_mc",1);
```

change 1 to -16384, like so:-

```
            this.createEmptyMovieClip("image_mc",-16384);
```

This might help someone still working on software from the stone-age -:)